# How I redirect output *and* set the CWD & ENV using Scala Process / ProcessBuilder?

Tags: scala, processbuilder

Let's say I have a command I need to run from Scala:

```
program -i inputFile
```

I can invoke this and capture the output in a file in Scala using:

```
val command = Seq("program", "-i", "inputFile")
val status = (command #> new File("capturedOutput")).!
```

But I need to set the environment and current working directory too.
This works:

```
val env = "KEY" -> "value"
val dir = new File("desiredWorkingDir")
val status = Process(command, dir, env).!
```

but I don't know how to put it all together, that is, to set env in my environment, run program in a certain directory, **and** capture the output in a file.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the intermediate `ProcessBuilder` instead of the DSL you tried at first. Also, the `ProcessLogger` class that is used for mapping outputs. So,

```
val pb: ProcessBuilder = Process(command, dir, env)
val runningCommand = pb.run(ProcessLogger(new File("capturedOutput")))
```

then wait for it to be done. You can also provide stream writers, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  This mostly worked.  I say mostly because the captured output was 4415488 bytes when it should have been 4424370.  It's as though a final flush of output buffers never happened.  I checked after `val status: Int = runningCommand.exitValue()` returned 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is an expansion on the answer @bob-dalgleish provided that I accepted.  I had a problem that the ProcessLogger was capturing most but not *all* of the output.  **If I closed the processLogger after getting the process's exitValue, I got all the output.**  Here is the full code:

```
val outputFilename = "capturedOutput-" + timestamp + ".txt"
val outputPath = dirForOutputFile + "/" + outputFilename

var env = "Key" -> "Value"
val dir: File = new File("desiredWorkingDir")
val command = Seq("program", "-i", "inputFile")

val pb: ProcessBuilder = Process(command, dir, env)
val processLogger = new FileProcessLogger(new File(outputPath))
val runningCommand = pb.run(processLogger)
val status: Int = runningCommand.exitValue()
processLogger.close()
```